# Error Installing Steam Dependencies

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, steam

I recently beansed my computer by installing a package while neglecting to note that it would remove a significant portion of the OS (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS). While I’ve reverted much of the damage caused by this error, I am running in to a problem when attempting to launch Steam. It tries to install dependencies but proceeds as follows:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages:
libc6:amd64 libc6:i386 libegl1:amd64 libegl1:i386 libgbm1:amd64 libgbm1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1:amd64 libgl1:i386 steam-libs-i386:i386

Press return to proceed with the installation: 
.........W: https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libegl1 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
libegl1 set to manually installed.
libgl1 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
libgl1 set to manually installed.
libc6 is already the newest version (2.35-0ubuntu3.1).
libc6:i386 is already the newest version (2.35-0ubuntu3.1).
libgbm1 is already the newest version (23.2~git2306280600.867851~oibaf~j).
libgbm1 set to manually installed.
libgl1-mesa-dri is already the newest version (23.2~git2306280600.867851~oibaf~j).
libgl1-mesa-dri set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1:i386 : Depends: libegl-mesa0:i386 but it is not installable
 libgbm1 : Breaks: libgbm1:i386 (!= 23.2~git2306280600.867851~oibaf~j) but 23.2~git2306200600.ba4201~oibaf~j is to be installed
 libgbm1:i386 : Breaks: libgbm1 (!= 23.2~git2306200600.ba4201~oibaf~j) but 23.2~git2306280600.867851~oibaf~j is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 23.2~git2306280600.867851~oibaf~j) but 23.2~git2306200600.ba4201~oibaf~j is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 23.2~git2306200600.ba4201~oibaf~j) but it is not installable
                        Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 23.2~git2306200600.ba4201~oibaf~j) but 23.2~git2306280600.867851~oibaf~j is to be installed
 libglx0:i386 : Depends: libglx-mesa0:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Notably (or maybe not) libglx or a related package is the package I remember installing that beansed the computer in the first place. I was rather cavalierly trying to resolve “broken packages” issues in a quest to fix another application.
Also, I am not sure why the reference to Unity3D appears in the first few lines- could that be a problem?
Thanks!

Edit: I’ve tried manually installing the dependencies listed but they all apparently ultimately depend on libglapi-mesa:i386, which wants me to uninstall essential system components and repeat the beansining I just tried to revert…
I’ve tried various methods to resolve the “held broken packages” but no dice so far.

Comment: "*the reference to Unity3D appears in the first few lines- could that be a problem?*" Not really. It's **a** problem, but it's not the cause of your version conflict ("`held broken packages`") that is your main problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an almost identical problem on my system, and I fixed it by purging the oibaf PPA:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

You'll need to install `ppa-purge` if it's not already installed.

I see "oibaf" in the version numbers in your logs above, so it appears you added this PPA at some point and are using packages from it. I suspect some conflict between that PPA and Ubuntu standard packages cropped up at some point recently.